# Google sheets/Drive- SUMIFS excluding a cell with no value

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet, drive

I'm trying to make a formula in Excel Drive were the amount of the invoice is divided by the amount of kilometres that a trip has made.
In column H I have all the invoiced amount per trip. In column E I have all the kilometres for that trip.
I want all the information in column H divided by the information in column E.
I only want the kilometres added in the formula, when the invoiced amount is filled.
I made the following formula, but due to my lack of knowledge it doesn't work.

=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$H:$H;Sheet1!$B:$B;2021)/SUMIFS(Sheet!$E:$E;Sheet!$B:$B;2021;Sheet!$H:$H;<>0)

Can anyone help me out or am I asking the impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see multiple issues with your formula,

Try this instead:

`=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$H:$H;Sheet1!$B:$B;"2021")/SUMIFS(Sheet1!$E:$E;Sheet1!$B:$B;"2021";Sheet1!$H:$H;"<>0")`

#### Issues:

- 2nd `SUMIFS` have `Sheet` instead of `Sheet1` (I assume you are looking into the same sheet which is `Sheet1`)
- surround the criterion with double quotes especially if it has a comparison operator such as `>, <, <>, =`. `2021` will do without double quotes but for best practice, surround it too.

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. A. I had the sheet names the same. That was a typo here on my end. the ">0" was the solution for my problem. I did not expect it to be so easy tbh. Thank you so much.